# PHP Array to SOAP 1.1 Request

Tags: php, xml, rest, soap, nusoap

I am trying to build the following request, but i fail at adding the XML attributes for blocks like `<SearchFlight xmlns="http://epowerv5.amadeus.com.tr/WS">` etc, and would like some help as this is pretty old and beyond me.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns="http://epowerv5.amadeus.com.tr/WS">
      <WSUserName>username</WSUserName>
      <WSPassword>Password</WSPassword>
    </AuthenticationSoapHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SearchFlight xmlns="http://epowerv5.amadeus.com.tr/WS">
      <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ ProviderType="OnlyAmadeus" RefundableType="AllFlights" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="0" MaxPrice="0">
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
          <DepartureDateTime>2018-11-19T00:01:00</DepartureDateTime>
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="MUC" />
          <DestinationLocation LocationCode="WAW" MultiAirportCityInd="true" />
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
          <DepartureDateTime>2018-11-25T00:01:00</DepartureDateTime>
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="WAW" MultiAirportCityInd="true" />
          <DestinationLocation LocationCode="MUC" />
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <TravelerInfoSummary>
          <AirTravelerAvail>
            <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" />
            <!--<PassengerTypeQuantity Code="CHD" />-->
          </AirTravelerAvail>
        </TravelerInfoSummary>
      </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
    </SearchFlight>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As you can see there is a lot of attributes here and i can't begin t tell you how confusing it is.

Comment: Yeah, I know how confusing it is, so I don't even try to convert it when I have to do SOAP requests. But, if you are still wanting to do it, why not use a ready made solutions like a library that does this conversion for you?

Comment: What do you you mean when you say you "fail at adding the XML attributes"? What does your code look like? What happens when you run it?